# Cannot run apache cordova on android mobile device

Tags: html, cordova-3

I am new to apache cordova and I am trying to run My first cordova application on android mobile phone (Version Android 4.1). I use "cordova run android" command on Comand Prompt. But then the app run on emulator not in the mobile device. Can anyone help me on these case.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify device like below command.

cordova run android --device

before you run cordova run android, I advice you to run the command adb devices to check if your device is found by the android sdk tools.

If it's not, you need to enable usb debugging on the device and install an adb driver for your device.

Comment: Please accept the answer if itprovided solution to question. It will help others to refer this. Thanks

Comment: cordova run android --device" is working.thanks Rupesh